# What is the max level cap?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

Some of the people in steam said that they reached 90 (most probably they cheated their way up since the game just came out), while some other web sources claim it is 40. I'm not sure which one is correct. By looking at the perk tree, if 40 is max level then you can't really unlock each and every perk in there (some perks cost 2 points, other costs 1 and some perks can be upgraded by points multiple times).

Anyway, what is the max level cap in AC:Origins?

Comment: This question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320544/leaving-siwa-to-find-aya-in-alexandria lists some of the zones as having a level of 99 though?

Comment: @DavidYell The author of the question said those two 99 level zones had no level marked on them so he made up those numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A tweet](https://twitter.com/AshrafAIsmail/status/881149171494989824?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgamingbolt.com%2Fassassins-creed-origins-level-cap-revealed-will-have-adjustable-aim-sensitivity-and-taming-ability) of the game director confirmed the level cap it's 40.

(content of tweet)

> Level cap is 40

As mentioned by @user199176

You can get skill points from tombs and other secrets on the map. Explore and do stuff and you'll get more points.

[UPDATE!](https://www.psu.com/news/assassins-creed-origins-level-cap-increase-hidden-ones-looms/)

- The hidden ones DLC increased the level cap to 45.
- The Curse of the Pharoahs DLC pushes it even further to 55

Comment: Should update the answer to include the new max level with DLCs which is 55

Answer (score -1):

If you own DLCs like the hidden ones your lvl won't be capped at lvl 40 and can go higher while non DLC owners lvl caps at lvl 40.