# Leaving Siwa to find Aya in Alexandria

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I have reached level 7 in the starting zone, Siwa, except for one location that is defended by fighters too powerful for me. I now have the quest to go to Alexandria to find my wife Aya, but it seems an oddly long journey by camel, and requires that I pass through very high level zones where I keep getting ambushed and one-shot killed.

Here's a list of the 34 map territories ordered by level. The two I'm safe in are *Lake Mareotis* and *Iment Nome*, but I can't reach either of those without going through *Quatara Depression* which is 37-40 and way beyond me at present.

Am I missing something, or am I supposed to just plough on through as many deaths as necessary?

| Territory | Approx. Level |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Siwa | 1 - 5 |
| 2. Iment Nome | 6 - 8 |
| 3. Lake Mareotis | 6 - 8 |
| 4. Alexandria | 9 - 12 |
| 5. Kanopos Nome | 11 - 13 |
| 6. Sap-Meh Nome | 12 - 15 |
| 7. Khensu Nome | 13 - 15 |
| 8. Sapi-Res Nome | 15 - 18 |
| 9. Giza | 17 - 20 |
| 10. Ka-Khem Nome | 17 - 20 |
| 11. Ineb-Hedjet Nome | 19 - 22 |
| 12. Memphis | 20 - 23 |
| 13. Saqquara Nome | 20 - 25 |
| 14. Faiyum | 24 - 29 |
| 15. Faiyum Oasis | 28 - 31 |
| 16. Uab Nome | 29 - 33 |
| 17. Atef-Pehu Nome | 30 - 33 |
| 18. Haueris Nome | 30 - 33 |
| 19. Herakleion Nome | 30 - 33 |
| 20. Im-Khent Nome | 30 - 33 |
| 21. Black Desert | 27 - 37 |
| 22. Libue | 31 - 34 |
| 23. Green Mountains | 32 - 35 |
| 24. Kyrenaika | 34 - 38 |
| 25. Desheret Desert | 34 - 40 |
| 26. Great Sand Sea | 36 - 40 |
| 27. White Desert | 36 - 40 |
| 28. White Desert Oasis | 36 - 40 |
| 29. Isolated Desert | 37 - 40 |
| 30. Marmarica | 37 - 40 |
| 31. Paraitonion | 37 - 40 |
| 32. Quatara Depression | 37 - 40 |
| 33. Great Green Sea |  |
| 34. Mesogeios Sea |  |

Comment: @Borodin & all - This question has a [meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12676/28182) regarding the formatting of tabular data. Please see the discussion there for further information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the quest description, it tells you to go speak to Hepzefa before you leave. When you do so, you get to confirm that you're ready to travel to Alexandria, and then the game time skips you over the desert travel and brings you to right outside Iment Nome and Lake Mareotis.

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you. I expected something like this and looked around for it, but missed it completely. I've now arrived in Alexandria via multiple deaths in the *Quattara Depression*, then *Iment Nome* and *Lake Mareotis*. It took me about two hours, but it must be nice to know that the game is tailored to let us stupids to progress. Everything is better now that I've met Aya, but I think I should begin the game again. I don't know whether to label this as bad game design or to be embarrassed at my stupidity!

Comment: It definitely is misleading. I can't remember if the quest marker points to Hepzefa, or if it just says to go talk to him.

Comment: You're right. On Youtube there's a cut scene that I don't remember seeing where Bayek talks about travelling to see his wife. At the same time there's a review that says how great AC:O is at feeding you the right quests at the right time. I've found that to be anything but true: at first it's about checking every landmark and scouting it to see whether you can play it. My table shows Alexandria to be levels 9-12, but I arrived there at level 8 and couldn't do a thing. Where did the intermdiate levels go?

Comment: *"If  you look at the quest description, it tells you to go speak to Hepzefa before you leave"* But it doesn't. The quest is called **Aya** and it told me to travel to Alexandria to see Aya. That is where I was confused; at level 7 I expected more guidance than to "go to Alexandria". I'm playing on PC; maybe that makes a difference, but it seems like a bug.

Comment: Perhaps it was the quest marker only that pointed to Hepzefa then? I remember knowing to talk to him first, so there must have been some sort of indication. I am past that part, so I unfortunately cannot fully confirm how exactly it points you in the correct direction. Maybe it is a bug with the PC version, I have been playing on the PS4. As for arriving under leveled in Alexandria, I ran through a bunch of quests as I found them in Iment Nome and Lake Mareotis. I assume those are supposed to be done before arriving at Alexandria. I was level 10 when I arrived.

Comment: Can you give me a better idea where you're teleported to when you speak to Hepzefa?

Comment: I was teleported to a desert location about a 5 minute horse ride from Alexandria. I set the quest to active, and just used follow road, and arrived shortly after.

Comment: I definitely had both questvtext and a quest marker point to him. Not sure if possibly it might have been a different quest... I might see uf i can replay the first bit to checj. If i avoid side quests it shouldnt take long. And the location you arrive is just south of Alexandria beyond the suburbs there. Not far southwest of the bottom of the lake from memory (Not far from the bandit necropolis there).